# python structured array composition and transformation

Tags: python, arrays, operators, coordinate-transformation, simplify

I created a script that collects a huge data from a .txt file into an array in the format I want [3: 4: n] and the information is recorded as follows (I think). The .txt file is in this format

1.000000e-01 1.000000e-01 1.000000e-01

1.000000e-01 2.000000e-01 3.000000e-01

3.000000e-01 2.000000e-01 1.000000e-01

1.000000e-01 2.000000e-01 4.000000e-01

and repeats for N times and I store basically from 4 lines into for lines (like a block) because I'm working with ASCII files from STL parts.

In this sense, I have this code:

```
f = open("camaSTLfinalmente.txt","r")

b_line = 0
Coord = []
Normal = []
Vertice_coord = []
Tri = []
blook = []

for line in f:
line = line.rstrip()
if(line):

    split = line.split()

    for axis in range(0,3):

        if(b_line == 0):                    #normal
            Normal.append(split[axis])
        else:                               #triangulo
            Vertice_coord.append(split[axis])

    if(b_line > 0):
        Tri.append(Vertice_coord)
        Vertice_coord = []

    if(b_line == 3):
        block.append(Normal)
        block.append(Tri)
        Coord.append(block)
        block = []
        Normal = []
        Tri = []
        b_line = 0
    else:
        b_line+=1

print(Coord[0]) #prints the follow line that I wrote after the code
```

the information is store in the way:
[['1.000000e-01', '1.000000e-01', '1.000000e-01'], [['1.000000e-01', '2.000000e-01', '3.000000e-01'], ['3.000000e-01', '2.000000e-01', '1.000000e-01'], ['1.000000e-01', '2.000000e-01', '-4.000000e-01']]]

Is there any way to simplify it?

I would like to take this opportunity to ask: I wanted to convert this information into numbers, and the ideal would be to read the number after the exponential (e) and change the numbers accordingly, that is, 1.000000e-01 goes to 0,1 (in order to make operations with a similar array where I store information from another .txt file with the same format)

Thanks for the attention,

Pedro

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the line `split = line.split()` to:

```
split = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
```

if you need the result to be in string and not float datatype:

```
split = [str(float(x)) for x in line.split()]
```

Comment: Ok the first part worked but when I get number like -6.275966e-05 or in the worst case like -6.275966e-17, it doesn't work ( what I'm saying is that the number is printed as it looks in txt file).
If the number looks like -6.275966e-02 the it goes to -0.06275966 . Im kind "new" at programming so I don't know if there is something that makes that not working with big exponencial numbers (numbers after the "e")

Comment: The issue is with limitation of python with decimal numbers. When there is too many decimal places, it will automatically convert the number to an 'e' format. A possible workaround is to use string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I fully understand what you want  but the following code produces the same `Coord`:

```py
coord = []
with open('camaSTLfinalmente.txt','r') as f:
    content = [line.strip().split() for line in f]
for i in range(len(content)//4): 
    coord.append([content[4*i], content[(4*i+1):(4*i+4)]])
```

Regarding the second question, as remarked in another answer, the easiest way to handle strings containing a number is to convert them to a number and then format them as string.

```py
s = '1.000000e-01'
n = float(s)
m = '{:.1f}'.format(n)
```

See the section about [string formatting in the Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

A couple remarks:

- Generally Stackoverflow doesn't like questions of the form "how do I improve this piece of code", try to ask more specific questions.
- The above assumes your file contains `4k` lines, change the integer division `...//4` accordingly if you have some lines left at the end that do not form a pack of 4.
- don't use capital letters for your variables. While style guides are not mandatory, it is good practice to follow them (Look up PEP-8, pylint, ...)